# How to visit vertices in undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, iteration, shortest-path

What are proper algorithms to visit all vertices of a undirected graph, from an arbitrary position? For example, given the following graph with 7 vertices, starting from #6:

[image]

There are many possible sequences:
67645321,
676421235,
6453212467,
...

How to iterate the vertices with shortest path (the first one)?
Thanks.

Comment: This must be NP Complete.

Comment: So if this is NPC, then for shortest path, it must iterate all solutions to find the shortest? Hmmm.is there any approach to find an optimal (probably not best) solution then?

Comment: You're not asking for all-pairs shortest path, right? I don't know if this is "shortest" but I'll use topological sort to break the graph into tree; and finally transverse all nodes of the tree.

Comment: I think toposort only applies to DAG? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sorry I'm not good in remembering the names of the algorithms. Mark start node as distance = 0, all nodes connected with distance = 0+1 = 1; all nodes that connected to nodes with distance = 1 => distance = 1+1=2, etc. If the node you wanna to mark a distance already have a distance value (equal or smaller), disconnect this edge. Now you should have a tree with minimal depth (or height) with the start node as root node.

Comment: Some more background: this is related to robot movement guidance in a known map. Movement is costly, while calculation is not. The total map is known for sure. So the key goal is to calculate the optimized path for traversing all nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Follow up with my comment above,

```
1-2-3
  | |
  4-5
  |
  6-7
```

Sort by node value, smaller value go first, which results:

```
6-+-4-+-2-+-1
  `-7 `-5 `-3
```

Transverse the tree:

```
6-4-2-1-2-3-2-4-5-4-6-7
```

Some more optimization can be made, e.g. for each node keep the 'depth' or weight of each 'child', transverse the shallow child / light child first.

```
6-+-(5)-4-+-(3)-2-+-(1)-1
  `-(1)-7 `-(1)-5 `-(1)-3
```

Thus we transverse as below:

```
6-7-6-4-5-4-2-1-2-3
```

May have more methods to optimize, good luck!

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired output of `67645321`.

Comment: Yes, I just keep thinking while typing. This 67645321 hint me a sudden thought if dynamic programming will do a better result than graphs algorithms. Hmm.....

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the node furthest away from your starting node, that would be the node where the shortest path from your starting node has a maximum length.   Call this node `Q`.
2. Calculate the distance from `Q` to all other nodes in your graph.  Call this distance `D1, D2, ...`.
3. Start walking at the starting node.
4. Always walk to the nearest unvisited node.
5. If there are more than one unvisited nodes within the same distance, i.e. if there are multiple unvisited nodes directly connected to the current one, walk to the one where `Di` is largest.  Always walk **away** from `Q`.

Given your example graph you find `Q=1` and `D1=0`, `D2=1`, `D3=2`, `D4=2`, `D5=3`, `D6=3`, `D7=4`.  Starting from 6 you have 4 and 7 as options, and you pick 7 because `D7>D4`.  From there you go to 4, because that's the nearest unvisited node.  Then to 5, because `D5>D2`.  Finally 3, 2, 1.

This algorithm is not perfect, and it needs some fine-tuning.  For example, when picking `Q` in step 1. you could end up with node 3, because it has the same distance from 6, so you need some additional heuristic to resolve ties,  maybe in favor of nodes where the fewest paths go.  So you won't get a perfect result, but I'd say you will get something reasonable.

Comment: I like this. I'm curious that whether this algorithm provides better solution for finding a longest path in a 2D grid from a fixed starting point.